# cs50 reverse pset 5 result1 dont return 1

Tags: c, cs50

1. List item

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "wav.h"

int check_format(WAVHEADER header);
int get_block_size(WAVHEADER header);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Ensure proper usage
    // TODO #1
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Invalid usage (CLA!)\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Open input file for reading
    // TODO #2

    // Set second cla to fname
    char *file_name = argv[1];

    // Open fname in read mode and store in wav
    FILE *wav = fopen(file_name, "r");

    // If wav can't be opened
    if (wav == NULL)
    {
        // Error message
        printf("Input is not a WAV file.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Read header
    // TODO #3

    WAVHEADER header; // Wav header

    // Read wav into address of header
    int result = fread(&header, sizeof(WAVHEADER), 1, wav);

    if (result != 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }


    // Use check_format to ensure WAV format
    // TODO #4
    check_format(header);

    // Open output file for writing
    // TODO #5

    // Setting filename to argv[2]
    char *outfile_name = argv[2];

    // Opening file in write mode
    FILE *outfile = fopen(outfile_name, "wb");

    // Check if outfile opened correctly
    if (outfile == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error outfile didn't open correctly!!!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Write header to file
    // TODO #6
    fwrite(&header, sizeof(WAVHEADER), 1, outfile);

    // Use get_block_size to calculate size of block
    // TODO #7
    int size_of_block = get_block_size(header);

    // Write reversed audio to file
    // TODO #8

    // Size of audio data
    fseek(wav, 0, SEEK_END); // end of file
    int file_size = ftell(wav); // current file position
    fseek(wav, 0, SEEK_SET); // back to begining of file

    // Checking if wav is open
    if (wav == NULL)
    {
        printf("wav is not opened\n");
    }
    
    // Sample size
    int a = fread(&(header.bitsPerSample), sizeof(header.bitsPerSample), 1, wav);
    // Checking if fread had an error
    if (a != 1)
    {
        printf("fread failed to read");
    }


    int sample_size = header.bitsPerSample / 8;

    int size = file_size - sizeof(WAVHEADER); // minus size of header
    int num_samples = size / sample_size;
    short* reversed = malloc(num_samples * 2 * sizeof(short));

    if (reversed == NULL)
    {
        printf("reversed array was equal to null");
        return 1;
    }

    if (num_samples / 2 != 0)
    {
         num_samples = num_samples - 1;
    }


        int result1 = fread(reversed, sample_size, 2 * num_samples, wav);

        if (result1 != 2 * num_samples)
        {
            printf("RESULT 1 DONT EQUAL 1\n");
            return 1;
        }

    for (int i = 0; i < num_samples / 2; i++)
    {
         // Store the pair of samples at index i
        short temp = reversed[2 * i];
        short temp1 = reversed[2 * i + 1];

        // Swap the pair of samples at index i with the pair at index num_samples / 2 - 1 - i
        reversed[2 * i] = reversed[2 * (num_samples / 2 - 1 - i)];
        reversed[2 * i + 1] = reversed[2 * (num_samples / 2 - 1 - i) + 1];

        // Put the stored samples at index num_samples / 2 - 1 - i
        reversed[2 * (num_samples / 2 - 1 - i)] = temp;
        reversed[2 * (num_samples / 2 - 1 - i) + 1] = temp1;

    }
    int result2 = fwrite(reversed, sample_size, num_samples, outfile);

    // Check if all audio was reversed
    if (result2 < num_samples)
    {
        printf("some audio not reversed");
    }

    // Close files
    fclose(outfile);
    fclose(wav);
    free(reversed);
    }


int check_format(WAVHEADER header)
{
    // TODO #4
    if (strncmp((char *) header.format, "WAVE", 4) == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("NOT A WAV FILE !\n");
        return 1;
    }
}

int get_block_size(WAVHEADER header)
{
    // TODO #7
    long total_channels = header.numChannels;
    long bits_per_sample = header.bitsPerSample;
    long block_size = total_channels * (bits_per_sample / 8);

    return (int) block_size;
}
```

result1 is not returning 1 so im assuming is num_samples or something else if someone could help me find my errors it would be very helpful.

ive tried ddb and cs50.ai but i cant seem to find the problem.

this is the error message
result1 dont return 1 so im assuming num_samples is wrong but im not sure and im hoping someone can see my error/errors

Comment: Hey there, maybe add C as a tag or have a look at https://cs50.stackexchange.com/

Comment: OT: `if (argc < 2)` should be `if (argc < 3)`. The value of `argc` is the number of valid *elements* in the `argv` array, *including* the first at index `0`. Related note: `argv[argc]` is specified to be a `NULL` pointer.

Comment: Your question is unclear. `result1` is not a function, so it cannot return anything. Do you mean the value returned by `fread` and assigned to `result1` is not 1? Re “this is the error message result1 dont return 1”: Is that the **exact text** of the error message? The error message is the grammatically incorrect “result1 dont return 1”? If it is not, edit the question to show the complete exact text of the error message, including surrounding context. Also, edit the question to provide a [mre]. The code in the question will not compile without `wav.h`.

Comment: result1 holds the return value of fread so it does return something its suppose to return 1 if not fread didnt complete correctly thanks for the other comment tho

Comment: reverse/ $ ./reverse input.wav output.wav
RESULT 1 DONT EQUAL 1

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems:

- You must open the binary file in binary mode to avoid end of line translation on legacy platforms:

  ```
  FILE *wav = fopen(file_name, "rb");
  ```
- There is no reason to re-read the number of bits per pixels from the stream after rewinding the stream with `fseek(wav, 0, SEEK_SET)`: this definitely produces an invalid count.  You might instead need to handle the endianness to convert the field `header.bitsPerSample` in case your current platform does not use little endian encodings.  And you should seek back to the position `sizeof(header)` instead of `0`.
- the test `if (num_samples / 2 != 0)` seems incorrect. You probably mean `if (num_samples % 2 != 0)`
- you assume at least 16 bits per sample and stereo (ie: numChannels == 2), but you should use the header fields for this information and handle more generic contents.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "wav.h"

int check_format(WAVHEADER header);
int get_block_size(WAVHEADER header);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Ensure proper usage
    // TODO #1
    if (argc < 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid usage: missing command line argument input file names\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Open input file for reading
    // TODO #2

    char *file_name = argv[1];
    FILE *wav = fopen(file_name, "rb");
    if (wav == NULL) {
        // Error message
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open %s: %s\n", file_name, strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }

    // Read header
    // TODO #3
    WAVHEADER header; // Wav header

    // Read wav into address of header
    if (fread(&header, sizeof(WAVHEADER), 1, wav) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot read WAV header from %s\n", file_name);
        fclose(wav);
        return 1;
    }

    // Use check_format to ensure WAV format
    // TODO #4
    if (check_format(header)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s is not a WAV file\n", file_name);
        fclose(wav);
        return 1;
    }

    // Open output file for writing
    // TODO #5

    // Setting filename to argv[2]
    char *outfile_name = argv[2];

    // Opening file in write mode
    FILE *outfile = fopen(outfile_name, "wb");
    if (outfile == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open %s: %s\n", outfile_name, strerror(errno));
        fclose(wav);
        return 1;
    }

    // Write header to file
    // TODO #6
    fwrite(&header, sizeof(WAVHEADER), 1, outfile);

    // Use get_block_size to calculate size of block
    // TODO #7
    int size_of_block = get_block_size(header);

    // Write reversed audio to file
    // TODO #8

    // Size of audio data
    long pos = ftell(wav);
    fseek(wav, 0, SEEK_END); // end of file
    long file_size = ftell(wav); // current file position
    fseek(wav, pos, SEEK_SET); // back to begining of samoples

    // Sample size (mono, stereo or more channels)
    int sample_size = (header.bitsPerSample / 8) * header.numChannels;
    long size = file_size - pos; // minus size of header
    long num_samples = size / sample_size;
    unsigned char *reversed = malloc(size);
    if (reversed == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot allocate %ld bytes for reversed array\n", size);
        fclose(wav);
        fclose(outfile);
        return 1;
    }

    long result1 = fread(reversed, sample_size, num_samples, wav);
    if (result1 != num_samples) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error reading samples from %s\n", file_name);
        fclose(wav);
        fclose(outfile);
        return 1;
    }

    for (long i = 0, j = num_samples - 1; i < j; i++, j++) {
        unsigned char sample[sample_size];
        memcpy(sample, &reversed[i * sample_size]);
        memcpy(&reversed[i * sample_size], &reversed[j * sample_size], sample_size);
        memcpy(&reversed[j * sample_size], sample, sample_size);
    }
    int result2 = fwrite(reversed, sample_size, num_samples, outfile);
    if (result2 < num_samples) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error writing samples to %s\n", outfile_name);
    }

    // Close files
    fclose(outfile);
    fclose(wav);
    free(reversed);
    return 0;
}

int check_format(WAVHEADER header) {
    // TODO #4
    if (memcmp(header.format, "WAVE", 4) == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}

int get_block_size(WAVHEADER header) {
    // TODO #7
    long total_channels = header.numChannels;
    long bits_per_sample = header.bitsPerSample;
    long block_size = total_channels * (bits_per_sample / 8);
    return (int)block_size;
}
```

Comment: ive implemented this and its still giving me the same error